# A couple in a dark room pulls 2 socks each from a shared drawer. What's the probablity of them getting exactly one & two pairs without trading?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A couple in a dark room pulls 2 socks each from a shared drawer. The drawer contains 4 blue, 7 red, and 3 yellow socks. The couple cannot trade socks. What is the probability of exactly one pair (of the same colour) being drawn? And what is the probability of both of them each getting a pair?

Similarly to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479554/drawer-contains-14-socks-if-i-randomly-pull-2-what-is-the-probability-that-i-w) I know that the probability of drawing a pair when only one person is drawing 2 socks from this drawer is

$$\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{14}{2}} + \frac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{14}{2}} + \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{14}{2}} = \frac{6}{91} + \frac{21}{91} + \frac{3}{91} = \frac{30}{91}$$

but I'm completely lost when it comes to drawing two pairs at once.

Additionally I know that the total amount of ways to draw these socks is $\binom{14}{2} \times \binom{12}{2} = 91\times66=6006$ since 2 socks are first drawn from 14 and then 2 socks are drawn from the remaining 12. This also means that the first person getting a pair and the second person getting any other 2 socks happen in $30\times\binom{12}{2}=1980$ out of the $6006$ ways (which is the same probability as $\frac{30}{91}$). But I'm not sure if this is useful for solving the problem.

I really need some insight for how to approach this problem as it's not the same thing as getting two pairs when drawing 4 or more socks/cards etc.

Comment: you can do it systematically. first, take the couple to be (person1, person2) where person1 picks first. how many ways can you pick a pair of blue socks for person1 then a pair of blue socks for person2, a pair of blue socks then a pair of red socks, a pair of blue socks then a pair of yellow socks, a pair of red socks then a pair of blue socks, a pair of red socks then a pair of red socks, a pair of red socks then a pair of yellow,.... finally divide the sum of these terms by the total number of ways to pick the socks :).

Comment: Yes that sounds quite right. Thanks for helping out :). I was hoping that a simpler method would be possible since I'm doing a larger problem with cards which gives me 13 different unsuited types of pairs (and 52 suited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *probability* has been asked for, we can, without loss of generality, simplify the problem to two draws of two socks

With $4$ blue, $7$ red and $3$ yellow,
P(both are pairs) $= \dfrac{\binom42\binom22 + \binom72\binom52+2[\binom42\binom72+ \binom42\binom32+\binom72\binom32]}{\binom{14}2\binom{12}2}$

Can you now proceed to the second part of he problem. There will be a number of cases that you will need to count, and **one warning**: your computation for one pair towards the end is actually computation for *at least one* pair.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look more closely at it tomorrow since it's quite late where I live. But it looks like your answer for getting two pairs only take blue+red pairs, blue+yellow pairs, & red+blue pairs into account for the two pair part (so no blue+blue or red+red pairs). I guess I could just simply expand your answer for the pairs where all four socks are the same color.

Comment: Also thank you for the hint, I believe I can deduce the 2nd part of the problem (exactly one pair between the couple) using your answer :)

Comment: You are right about the first part, added.

Answer (score 0):

Since true blue anil has answered the *second* question, I will answer the first question.  What is the probability that they get exactly one pair?

The probability is

$$\frac{N}{\binom{14}{2} \times \binom{12}{2}} = \frac{N}{6006}. \tag1 $$

Assume that the people are A and B, and that A pulls two socks out first.

In computing the denominator in (1) above, for convenience, order is construed to be relevant.  That is, A pulling a pair of blue socks, then B pulling a pair of red socks is construed to be distinct from A pulling a pair of red socks, then B pulling a pair of blue socks.

Therefore, the numerator, $(N)$ must be computed in a consistent manner.

Further, by symmetry, the number of combinations where A pulls a pair and B does not must equal the number of combinations where A does not pull a pair and B does pull a pair.

Therefore, I will compute twice the number of combinations where A pulls a pair and B does not.

In all of the possibilities below, I will use the syntax: 
b-r to denote the number of ways that B can pull a blue and red. 
b-y to denote the number of ways that B can pull a blue and yellow. 
r-y to denote the number of ways that B can pull a red and yellow.

- A pulls a blue pair. 
  $\binom{4}{2} = 6~$ ways. 
  Then, there are 2 blue, 7 red, 3 yellow remaining.
  Therefore, 
  b-r + b-y + r-y equals 
  $(2 \times 7) + (2 \times 3) + (7 \times 3) = 41.$ 
  Overall partial sum is
  $6 \times 41 = 246.$
- A pulls a red pair. 
  $\binom{7}{2} = 21~$ ways. 
  Then, there are 4 blue, 5 red, 3 yellow remaining.
  Therefore, 
  b-r + b-y + r-y equals 
  $(4 \times 5) + (4 \times 3) + (5 \times 3) = 47.$ 
  Overall partial sum is
  $21 \times 47 = 987.$
- A pulls a yellow pair. 
  $\binom{3}{2} = 3~$ ways. 
  Then, there are 4 blue, 7 red, 1 yellow remaining.
  Therefore, 
  b-r + b-y + r-y equals 
  $(4 \times 7) + (4 \times 1) + (7 \times 1) = 39.$ 
  Overall partial sum is
  $3 \times 39 = 117.$

Therefore,

$$N = 2 \times \left(246 + 987 + 117\right) = 2700.$$

Therefore, the probability of this happening is

$$\frac{2700}{6006} = \frac{450}{1001}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer! I will leave an upvote once I've reached 15 reputation. I'm not sure which answer to accept since you and true blue anil answered one half each, and both were very helpful.

Comment: @sitron true blue anil answered first, so I suggest accepting his answer.

Comment: Yes, that seems fair, and now I got clarification about my extra question about two pairs of the same color

Comment: But I very much appreciate your answer too :)